# How to use Fable compiler without webpack fable-loader?

Tags: webpack, f#, fable-f#

I am experimenting with F# and using Fable to compile to JavaScript. The story is good so far. However, I have projects that do not use Webpack bundler where I wish to use Fable. NPM module `fable-compiler` does not expose any CLI command to compile simple `.fs` file to a `.js` file.

I wonder if this is possible. If yes, how? Basically, I need a plain output like the way `Fable REPL` produces i.e. distinct `.js` file side-by-side for each `.fs` file.

> *Ideally, I assume it should be similar to BuckleScript/Reason compiler but I could not find any documentation so far*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the [fable-splitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fable-splitter) package instead of `fable-compiler`.

Using this is as simple as `fable-splitter myProject.fsproj -o outputDir`

A sample project using this approach can be found [here](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable2-samples/tree/master/nodejs).